# get most two recent items ordered by date from a dictionary array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Been looking in similar threads but just can't to wrap my head around it. My current item seems way more complicated even for me. Here is my json (sorry it is a bit long):

```
items = [
      {
        'name' : 'Books',
        'types':[
          {
              'name' : 'Hard Cover',
              'genres':[
                {
                  'genre' : 'Romance',

                  'added_date' : '2018-09-15',

                  'id':1
                },
                {
                  'genre' : 'Crime',

                  'added_date' : '2018-10-01',

                  'id' : 2
                }

              ],
              'cover':['pic1.png','pic2.png']
              },
              {
                'name' : 'Audio',
                'genres':[
                  {
                    'genre' : 'Memoir',

                    'added_date' : '2018-08-01',

                    'id' : 3
                  }

                ],
                'pictures':['pic3.png','pic4.png']
           },

         ]

      },

      {
        'name' : 'Videos',
        'types':[
          {
              'name' : 'English',
              'genres':[
                {
                  'genre' : 'Comedy',

                  'added_date' : '2018-10-14',

                  'id' : 12
                }

              ],
              'pictures':['pic5.png','pic6.png']
              }

         ]

      }
  ];
```

The output I want now is to get the 3 items which were added recently based on their added_date field in genres block. Now for those items, I need return an array with dictionary elements with full path:

```
   [
    {'id':7,'genre':'Romance','name':'Hard Cover','added_date':'2018-09-16','top_parent_name':'Books'},
    {'id':8,'genre':'Memoir','name':'Audio','added_date':'2018-09-15','top_parent_name':'Books'},


     ]
```

Based on added_date, to get the latest 3 items that were added through out the whole object and its relavant information. I hope this makes sense.

So far, I have thought of the following but it quickly became cumbersome.

```
items.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
      const types: any[] = value['types'];

      types.forEach(function(value_t, index_t, array_t){
        const genres: any[] = value_model['genes'];
       //loop again to get date....

      });



  });
```

Comment: Can you clarify your output (i.e. put *exactly* the output you would want from that input)? It's hard to make sense, given multiple genres. Also what you mean by top 3.

Comment: Can you see now @MattWay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I make sense of the question correctly, you want the most recent 3 added by date, flattened into a particular format. If that is the case, then the answer will probably depend on how much data you are processing. One option is to build a fully flat array of your data, and then sort by date. For which I would use an array flattening utility function (i've included one, but use lodash if you can)

For example:

```
const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])

const mapGenres = (topName, name, genres) => genres.map(genre => ({
  name,
  topName,
  ...genre
})

const result = flatten(items.map(({ name, types }) => 
  flatten(types.map(type => mapGenres(name, type.name, type.genres)))
))

result.sort((a, b) => return b.added_date.localeCompare(a.added_date))
```

*This is untested*, but should be fairly straight forward. Nested levels of flattening maps, producing your desired output at the leaves.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach.  First extract the data you want into objects by doing several levels of mapping and then several levels of flattening.  (`Array.prototype.flatten` is not ubiquitous enough to use yet, I believe, so I use `reduce(concat)`.)

Then when you have the data extracted into a flat list, sort it descending on the date.  Finally, grab the top three values:

```js
const items = [{"name": "Books", "types": [{"cover": ["pic1.png", "pic2.png"], "genres": [{"added_date": "2018-09-15", "genre": "Romance", "id": 1}, {"added_date": "2018-10-01", "genre": "Crime", "id": 2}], "name": "Hard Cover"}, {"genres": [{"added_date": "2018-08-01", "genre": "Memoir", "id": 3}], "name": "Audio", "pictures": ["pic3.png", "pic4.png"]}]}, {"name": "Videos", "types": [{"genres": [{"added_date": "2018-10-14", "genre": "Comedy", "id": 12}], "name": "English", "pictures": ["pic5.png", "pic6.png"]}]}];

const tops = items.map(item => item.types.map(type => type.genres.map(genre => ({
  name: type.name,
  top_name: item.name,
  ...genre
})))).reduce(
  (a, b) => a.concat(b), []
).reduce(
  (a, b) => a.concat(b), []
).sort(
  (a, b) => a.added_date > b.added_date ? -1 : a.added_date < b.added_date ? 1 : 0
).slice(0, 3)

console.log(tops)
```

There are certainly some inefficiencies in these separate loops, and the sort is likely `O(n * log(n))`, whereas even a three-part maximum should be `O(n)`.  But I would only worry about these if it turns out to be a bottleneck in your application.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Sauyet. Actually, that is much readable. Let me check it out.